# How to use COUNTIFS to count mutually exclusively from several criteria ranges?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a row in Excel comprising sequential data. For simplicity's sake, lets say there are only two values that each cell can contain: "A" or "B".

I need to count how many times an A appears in the data with a B appearing in the next place, in the second next place, OR in the third next place.

For example:

```
A B A A B B A B B B
```

The desired result would be 3 (exclusive cases of A's followed by a B up to the three next places).

Summing three separate COUNTIFS functions evaluating all cells containing an A with a B one place right, two places right, and three places right adds up the A's potentially more than once. The incorrect result here, which is the only one I have managed to get so far, is 7. In other words, I can't seem to fit the OR logic anywhere in this function.

Comment: Why not `4` the second `A` has a `B` two places to the right?

Comment: is the data in a string in one cell or is it one letter in its own cell in a row

Comment: Yes, Scott, my mistake. The desired result would of course be 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably try to first combine the cells in the range into a string using concat and then search within that string for the string types you want using "AB", "A?B", and "A??B".

Check this [post](https://www.get-digital-help.com/count-a-given-pattern-in-a-cell-value/) and expand on it to account for the different possibilities.

Comment: This solved the problem. I used `CONCATENATE` to convert each four-cell sequence in the entire data set with a @ symbol denoting the first data point and a vertical bar denoting the latter ones, for example, the first cell in the data set `A B A A B B A B B` would be converted into `@A|B|A|A`. Counting all cells comprising `@A*` and `*|B*` gave the desired result.